# vb UrlEncoding is not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, url, uri, urlencode

Hi I am using the below code for encoding a url in vb but I am not getting the expected output please help.

```
  Dim CancelURL As String = "http://d41a9833f1464bd0a764b77669049fc8.cloudapp.net/Login/Appointment Booking/CancelAppointment.aspx?" &
                                     "clhid=" & objLogin.LoggedHeadOrgID &
                                     "&apptid=" & objAppt.ID
            strTemplateString = strTemplateString.Replace("[Cancellation link]", Uri.EscapeDataString(CancelURL))
```

this is my code and I ended up with this

```
http%3A%2F%2Fd41a9833f1464bd0a764b77669049fc8.cloudapp.net%2FLogin%2FAppointment%20Booking%2FCancelAppointment.aspx%3Fclhid%3D22b53721-a127-41be-95ca-7512b5caad84%26apptid%3Debb09af1-c521-47d6-9a7d-0b411ef3937d
```

But I am expecting

```
http://d41a9833f1464bd0a764b77669049fc8.cloudapp.net/Login/Appointment Booking/CancelAppointment.aspx?clhid=3D22b53721-a127-41be-95ca-7512b5caad84&apptid=Debb09af1-c521-47d6-9a7d-0b411ef3937d
```

Comment: Why is that not the expected output?  What *is* your expected output?

Comment: i need http://d41a9833f1464bd0a764b77669049fc8.cloudapp.net/Login/Appointment%20Booking/CancelAppointment.aspx?clhid=somevalue like this

Comment: Don't post substantive clarifications in the comments section; instead, update your question.  You need to include all relevant information in the question itself.

Comment: Then don't URLEncode the hostname.

Comment: @roryap thanks for the suggestion will to do it right away

Comment: hi anyone can help plz i will be thankful

Comment: @Tanmay -- I thought you were already past this question since  Phylogenesis gave you the answer in his or her comment above...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Uri.EscapeUriString` as this does not escape the *scheme*:

```
Uri.EscapeUriString("http://foo.com/this is a url")

'output
http://foo.com/this%20is%20a%20url
```